# some of my apps takes too long to open from terminal, sometimes they don't even open at all on ubuntu 21.10

Tags: package-management, wine, 21.10

for instance, when I ran this command:
`$ wine winecfg`

I got this error msg after waiting for a long time:
`0158:err:environ:run_wineboot boot event wait timed out`

What might be the problem?

Comment: Does this only happen with wine if not can you give more examples?

Comment: same thing happened with ruby, codeblocks, and every other app installed with wine

Comment: where ruby and codeblocks installed with wine

Comment: What is your wine version and where did you install from like Ubuntu repo or the wine ppa

Comment: codeblocks and ruby wasn't installed with wine.

Comment: wine version is wine-7.0